# Add Fisheye effect to images at runtime using OpenGL ES

Tags: iphone, graphics, opengl-es

my situation is that i receive different images from the server onto the iPhone client.

what i need to do is to add a Fisheye effect to those images.

what my hallucination is that i can build a dome object, then attach images to it as they come to me.

if anyone can give me any pointers to the right direction i'll be thankful.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Have you tried looking at [Paul Bourke's example code for OpenGL](http://paulbourke.net/miscellaneous/lenscorrection/)? I don't know if it's compatible with OpenGL-ES. Note the feedback about using "glCopyTexSubImage2D instead of doing a slow glReadPixels".

AFAICT, Paul Bourke is doing essentially what you said, creating a distorted grid (your "dome object") to lay the image on.
According to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4279922/algorithm-for-creating-fisheye-effect-from-a-normal-image), that's a good approach.

**Updated:**

Or, since iPhone's OpenGL-ES supports shaders (at least in some versions), you could get better performance using a plane distortion technique like [this](http://adrianboeing.blogspot.com/2011/01/webgl-tunnel-effect-explained.html). You'd just have to change the formulas for `uv.x` and `uv.y`. Then you wouldn't need to be concerned about breaking up the image into a grid of small polygons... you'd have single-pixel resolution for free. :-)

Hm... maybe you need to define what kind of "fisheye" effect you are looking for. Seems there is [more than one](http://paulbourke.net/miscellaneous/domefisheye/fisheye/).

See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4246143/using-both-programmable-and-fixed-pipeline-functionality-in-opengl).

**Updated again:**

Here is some GLSL code I wrote to do a lens effect in a shader. I believe it's a hemispherical fisheye lens. It runs under WebGL, which uses OpenGL ES, so it should be adaptable for iPhone.

```
#ifdef GL_ES
precision highp float;
#endif

uniform vec2 resolution;
uniform vec4 mouse;
uniform sampler2D tex0;

// lens
void main(void)
{
    vec2 p = gl_FragCoord.xy / resolution.xy;
    vec2 m = mouse.xy / resolution.xy;
    float lensSize = 0.4;

    vec2 d = p - m;
    float r = sqrt(dot(d, d)); // distance of pixel from mouse

    vec2 uv;
    if (r >= lensSize) {
        uv = p;
    } else {
        // Thanks to Paul Bourke for these formulas; see
        // http://paulbourke.net/miscellaneous/lenscorrection/
        // and .../lenscorrection/lens.c
        // Choose one formula to uncomment:
        // SQUAREXY:
        // uv = m + vec2(d.x * abs(d.x), d.y * abs(d.y));
        // SQUARER:
        uv = m + d * r; // a.k.a. m + normalize(d) * r * r
        // SINER:
        // uv = m + normalize(d) * sin(r * 3.14159 * 0.5);
        // ASINR:
        // uv = m + normalize(d) * asin(r) / (3.14159 * 0.5);
    }

    vec3 col = texture2D(tex0, vec2(uv.x, -uv.y)).xyz;

    gl_FragColor = vec4(col, 1.0);
}
```

To test this, paste it into [ShaderToy](http://www.iquilezles.org/apps/shadertoy/) in a WebGL-enabled browser. Set input 0 to a texture like http://www.iquilezles.org/apps/shadertoy/presets/tex0.jpg or http://www.iquilezles.org/apps/shadertoy/presets/tex4.jpg

Click the play button, and drag the mouse around on the rendering area. The lens is centered on the mouse pointer.

Comment: just thinking crazy here, can't i have my 3D model made on Blender or something, then map my texture to that in OpenGLES ? since i can't really rely on shaders for we have support for 3G iPhones

Comment: Sure, if you know how to model such a shape in Blender, and map your texture to it.

Comment: @MarkEssel: Glad it was helpful to you. BTW there is now a full ShaderToy web site, shadertoy.com, where you can search for terms like "fisheye" and hopefully find code that does what you need.

Answer (score 1):

status=MagickImplodeImage(magick_wand, -3);