# Shader - Anti fisheye by "pulling" pixels

Tags: glsl, shader, fragment-shader

I would like to fix the distortion of this image :

[image]

Sorry for the quality, but this is the best example I could find.

I don't know if fixing this distortion is possible (I would like to have straight doors, and a straight ceiling), but basically, instead of pushing the pixels outside of the image (red arrows) that is adding a blur effect, I would like to do the opposite (green arrows), to pull the pixels towards the center.

If you have any idea, that would be awesome. Other solutions are welcomed as well !

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For the definition of the fisheye effect, you've to associate an angle (*alpha*) to the diagonal (*d*) of the viewport.
The diagonal of the viewport is the diameter of of circle which includes the entire viewport.

[image]

The relation between the radius of the perimeter circle (*r*) and the angle (*alpha*) is:

```
r = tan(alpha / 2)
```

In the following `eye_angle` corresponds to *alpha* and `half_dist` to `r`:

```
float half_angle = eye_angle/2.0;
float half_dist = tan(half_angle);
```

With the the aspect ration of the viewport (`aspect`) and is the normalized device position of the fragment on the viewport `ndcPos` the position `P` can be calculated. In normalized device space the `x` and `y` are in range [-1, 1]:

```c
vec2 vp_scale = vec2(aspect, 1.0);
vec2 P = ndcPos * vp_scale;
```

For each point (`P`) on the view port the relative distance (`rel_dist`) to the center of the viewport in relation to the perimeter circle has to be calculated. And the relative position (`rel_P`) of the point (`P`) in the relation to the aspect ration is needed:

```c
float vp_dia   = length(vp_scale);
float rel_dist = length(P) / vp_dia;  
vec2  rel_P    = normalize(P) / normalize(vp_scale);
```

The fisheye effect is caused by the projection of a spherical surface on a plane. To calculate from and to the projection, the relation between the arc length and the distance to the center of the plane has to be found:

[image]

If the radius of a circle is 1, the length of the arc is equal the angle of the arc segment in radians. So the relation between the distance to the point *P* and the angle *beta* is:

```
|P|/r = tan(beta)
beta = atan(|P|/r)
```

If the projection from the spherical surface to the plane is:

```c
float beta    = rel_dist * half_angle;
vec3  pos_prj = rel_P * tan(beta) / half_dist;
```

And the projection from the plane to the spherical surface is:

```c
float beta    = atan(rel_dist * half_dist);
vec2  pos_prj = rel_P * beta / half_angle;
```

See the following WebGL example which uses an fragment shader where the algorithm is implemented. The angle *alpha* is set be the uniform variable `u_alpha`.
If `u_alpha > 0.0`, then the projection form spherical surface to the plane is calculated.
If `u_alpha < 0.0`, then the projection from the plane to the spherical surface is calculated.

```js
(function loadscene() {    

var canvas, gl, vp_size, texture, prog, bufObj = {};

function initScene() {

    canvas = document.getElementById( "ogl-canvas");
    gl = canvas.getContext( "experimental-webgl" );
    if ( !gl )
      return;

    texture = new Texture( "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Rabbid76/graphics-snippets/master/resource/texture/supermario.jpg" ); 
    texture.bound = false;

    progDraw = gl.createProgram();
    for (let i = 0; i < 2; ++i) {
        let source = document.getElementById(i==0 ? "draw-shader-vs" : "draw-shader-fs").text;
        let shaderObj = gl.createShader(i==0 ? gl.VERTEX_SHADER : gl.FRAGMENT_SHADER);
        gl.shaderSource(shaderObj, source);
        gl.compileShader(shaderObj);
        let status = gl.getShaderParameter(shaderObj, gl.COMPILE_STATUS);
        if (!status) alert(gl.getShaderInfoLog(shaderObj));
        gl.attachShader(progDraw, shaderObj);
        gl.linkProgram(progDraw);
    }
    status = gl.getProgramParameter(progDraw, gl.LINK_STATUS);
    if ( !status ) alert(gl.getProgramInfoLog(progDraw));
    progDraw.inPos = gl.getAttribLocation(progDraw, "inPos");
    progDraw.u_time = gl.getUniformLocation(progDraw, "u_time");
    progDraw.u_resolution = gl.getUniformLocation(progDraw, "u_resolution");
    progDraw.u_texture = gl.getUniformLocation(progDraw, "u_texture");
    progDraw.u_angle = gl.getUniformLocation(progDraw, "u_angle");
    gl.useProgram(progDraw);

    var pos = [ -1, -1, 1, -1, 1, 1, -1, 1 ];
    var inx = [ 0, 1, 2, 0, 2, 3 ];
    bufObj.pos = gl.createBuffer();
    gl.bindBuffer( gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, bufObj.pos );
    gl.bufferData( gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array( pos ), gl.STATIC_DRAW );
    bufObj.inx = gl.createBuffer();
    bufObj.inx.len = inx.length;
    gl.bindBuffer( gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, bufObj.inx );
    gl.bufferData( gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, new Uint16Array( inx ), gl.STATIC_DRAW );
    gl.enableVertexAttribArray( progDraw.inPos );
    gl.vertexAttribPointer( progDraw.inPos, 2, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0 ); 
    
    gl.enable( gl.DEPTH_TEST );
    gl.clearColor( 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0 );

    window.onresize = resize;
    resize();
    requestAnimationFrame(render);
}

function resize() {
    vp_size = [window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight];
    canvas.width = vp_size[0];
    canvas.height = vp_size[1];
}

function render(deltaMS) {

    scale = document.getElementById( "scale" ).value / 100 * 2.0 - 1.0;

    gl.viewport( 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height );
    gl.clear( gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | gl.DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT );
   
    texture.bound = texture.bound || texture.bind( 0 );
    gl.uniform1i(progDraw.u_texture, 0);
    gl.uniform1f(progDraw.u_time, deltaMS/2000.0);
    gl.uniform2f(progDraw.u_resolution, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    gl.uniform1f(progDraw.u_angle, scale * Math.PI * 0.9);
    gl.drawElements( gl.TRIANGLES, bufObj.inx.len, gl.UNSIGNED_SHORT, 0 );
    
    requestAnimationFrame(render);
}  

class Texture {
    constructor( name, dflt ) {
        let texture = this;
        this.dflt = dflt || [128,128,128,255]
        let image = { "cx": this.dflt.w || 1, "cy": this.dflt.h || 1, "plane": this.dflt.p || this.dflt };
        this.size = [image.cx, image.cy];
        this.dummyObj = Texture.createTexture2D( image, true )
        this.image = new Image(64,64);
        this.image.setAttribute('crossorigin', 'anonymous');
        this.image.onload = function () {
            let cx = 1 << 31 - Math.clz32(texture.image.naturalWidth);
            if ( cx < texture.image.naturalWidth ) cx *= 2;
            let cy = 1 << 31 - Math.clz32(texture.image.naturalHeight);
            if ( cy < texture.image.naturalHeight ) cy *= 2;
            var canvas = document.createElement( 'canvas' );
            canvas.width  = cx;
            canvas.height = cy;
            var context = canvas.getContext( '2d' );
            context.drawImage( texture.image, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height );
            texture.textureObj = Texture.createTexture2D( canvas, true );
            texture.size = [cx, cy];
        }
        this.image.src = name;
    }
    static createTexture2D( image, flipY ) {
        let t = gl.createTexture();
        gl.activeTexture( gl.TEXTURE0 );
        gl.bindTexture( gl.TEXTURE_2D, t );
        gl.pixelStorei( gl.UNPACK_FLIP_Y_WEBGL, flipY != undefined && flipY == true );
        if ( image.cx && image.cy && image.plane )
            gl.texImage2D( gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, gl.RGBA, image.cx, image.cy, 0, gl.RGBA, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, new Uint8Array(image.plane) );
        else
            gl.texImage2D( gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, gl.RGBA, gl.RGBA, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, image );
        gl.texParameteri( gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, gl.LINEAR );
        gl.texParameteri( gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, gl.LINEAR );
        gl.texParameteri( gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_S, gl.REPEAT );
        gl.texParameteri( gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_T, gl.REPEAT );
        gl.bindTexture( gl.TEXTURE_2D, null );
        return t;
    }
    bind( texUnit = 0 ) {
        gl.activeTexture( gl.TEXTURE0 + texUnit );
        if ( this.textureObj ) { 
            gl.bindTexture( gl.TEXTURE_2D, this.textureObj );
            return true;
        }
        gl.bindTexture( gl.TEXTURE_2D, this.dummyObj );
        return false;
    }
};

initScene();

})();
```

```css
html,body { margin: 0; overflow: hidden; }
#gui { position : absolute; top : 0; left : 0; }
```

```html
<script id="draw-shader-fs" type="x-shader/x-fragment">
precision mediump float;

uniform float     u_time;
uniform vec2      u_resolution;
uniform float     u_angle;
uniform sampler2D u_texture;

void main()
{
    vec2 uv = gl_FragCoord.xy / u_resolution;
    vec2 ndcPos = uv * 2.0 - 1.0;

    float aspect = u_resolution.x / u_resolution.y;
    
    float eye_angle = abs(u_angle);
    float half_angle = eye_angle/2.0;
    float half_dist = tan(half_angle);

    vec2  vp_scale = vec2(aspect, 1.0);
    vec2  P = ndcPos * vp_scale; 
    
    float vp_dia   = length(vp_scale);
    float rel_dist = length(P) / vp_dia;  
    vec2  rel_P = normalize(P) / normalize(vp_scale);

    vec2 pos_prj = ndcPos;
    if (u_angle > 0.0)
    {
        float beta = rel_dist * half_angle;
        pos_prj = rel_P * tan(beta) / half_dist;  
    }
    else if (u_angle < 0.0)
    {
        float beta = atan(rel_dist * half_dist);
        pos_prj = rel_P * beta / half_angle;
    }

    vec2 uv_prj = pos_prj * 0.5 + 0.5;
    vec2 rangeCheck = step(vec2(0.0), uv_prj) * step(uv_prj, vec2(1.0));   
    if (rangeCheck.x * rangeCheck.y < 0.5)
        discard;

    vec4 texColor = texture2D(u_texture, uv_prj.st);
    gl_FragColor = vec4( texColor.rgb, 1.0 );
}
</script>

<script id="draw-shader-vs" type="x-shader/x-vertex">
precision mediump float;

attribute vec2 inPos;

void main()
{
    gl_Position = vec4( inPos.xy, 0.0, 1.0 );
}
</script>

<canvas id="ogl-canvas" style="border: none"></canvas>
<form id="gui" name="inputs">
<input type="range" id="scale" min="0" max="100" value="20"/>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

This kind of distortion is a property of a camera. If you have access to the camera used to take the picture, you can calibrate it in order to extract the deformation it applies. Otherwise, you can still use some general equations. Have a look at Paul Bourke's [article](http://paulbourke.net/dome/fisheyecorrect/), this Stack Overflow [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6030814/add-fisheye-effect-to-images-at-runtime-using-opengl-es) or this Shader Toy [example](https://www.shadertoy.com/view/td2GzW), to see how it could be done.

Comment: The distortion in this picture is not related to the camera, it's due to a stereographic projection (it's a 360 picture). I'm the creator of the shadertoy link you provided, but it does the red arrows solution, not the green arrows.

Comment: I misunderstood your question, sorry! Obviously, you already knew about lens rectification ^^.